# Know which team that is assosiated with an xcode project

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have an app that I need to associate to a certain team. The problem is that my client got two teams named the exact same thing. When I try to select a team in general tab (the same place where you set bundle identifier and version info) in xcode I have no clue which team is which. Is there a possibility to see the team ids as well, that basically would solve my problem.

Comment: If the edit is the answer to your question, then post it as an answer. Stackoverflow is not a forum. See [faq].

Comment: No it is not an answer it is a clarification on where the setting is found. But i definitely see that instead of clarifying my question it added to the confusion. I'll edit my question in a better way.